# onclick not working for inflated layout

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have a custom class which is extended from Relative Layout. In my xml there is linear layout and a button inside it. When i inflated this and try to use with onclick, it doesn't work. But  if i don't use a button, click works. This is the code:

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/inflated_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="@drawable/en_ad_purplebutton">
             <Button
                    android:id="@+id/general_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/en_button_positive"
                    android:textColor="@color/en_white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:clickable="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

CustomClass:

```
@Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    init();
}

private void init(){
    inf.inflate(R.layout.uc_button_positive, this);
    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.general_button);        
}
```

This is the code i use this custom class

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/finansbank.enpara"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="vertical" >


     <mypakage.customClass
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:text="deneme"
        android:onClick="go"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also tried it and saw that and it's not work,
And found that Need to do an event like this:

```
layout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your layout,
            container, false);


Button b=(Button)layout .findViewById(R.id.view);
    v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

It works great!!

Comment: But i want this custom class to work like a custom button which can dynamically handle any method submitted in onclick attribute of xml.

Comment: so add the setOnClick Listener in the custom button class

Comment: The strange thing is when i remove the button inside the linear layout. It works..

Comment: If i add setOnClickListener to my custom class. I need to set a job that says when i click this mission will be handled. But i want to use this class in different activities have different methods. I want to set onclick methods in the xml which belongs to the activity or by code in the activity class. I can't set a default function.